# Show alarm/notification at a particular date

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Briefly, I have a database table of events with start date and end date as columns (expressed as unix time stamps - milliseconds). What I want is to fire up a notification or an alarm at every end date of my events. How should I do this?

I thought it might work this : create a service that queries the database every 1 minute and when the current calendar instance equals the end date from my table show up a notification. But I don't think this is the right approach.

What is your opinion , how should I do this?

Comment: you can use the concept of pending Intent.

Comment: I tried to use an Alarm Manager , but I don't know how to add more than one alarm to it without overriding the current one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, alarmTime_id, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
                         alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmTime, pendingIntent);
```

use unique `alarmTime_id` each time.

Comment: That's I was looking for. Thank you . I was confused about that id , now I know how to use it.